# How to send email in java GWT

Tags: java, gwt

I am using this code in my java GWT application

```
        public String greetServer(String input) throws Exception {
    try{
    Properties props = new Properties();

     props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.port", "25");
    props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.random.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.user", "foo@bar.com");
    props.setProperty("mail.password", "000000000");

    Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport();

    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    message.setSubject("hello");
    message.setContent("helloo sss", "text/plain");
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress("junaidp@gmail.com"));

    transport.connect();
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
    transport.close();
    } catch(NoSuchProviderException e){
        throw new Exception(e);
      }

    return input;

}
```

Error:              javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: smtp.random.com, port: 25;
  nested exception is:
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

if i use

```
            props.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.live.com");
            and use my hotmail account , it gives this error 

           javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address
```

Any idea what could be the solution

thanks

Comment: Connect to an SMTP server that is listening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's some Gmail settings which work for me:

```
//these are fed into the Properties object below:
mail.smtp.starttls.enable = true
mail.transport.protocol   = smtp
mail.smtp.auth            = true
```

and some Java:

```
Properties properties = ...

javax.mail.Session session = javax.mail.Session.getInstance(properties, null);
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", username, password);
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used [Simple Java Mail](http://www.simplejavamail.org) in a GWT project. You might want to try it. It's very simple to configure.

There are lots of example there, including one of sending using [gmail's SMTP server using for example TLS](http://www.simplejavamail.org/#section-gmail):

```
Email email = new Email.Builder()
    .from("Michel Baker", "m.baker@mbakery.com")
    .to("mom", "jean.baker@hotmail.com")
    .to("dad", "StevenOakly1963@hotmail.com")
    .subject("My Bakery is finally open!")
    .text("Mom, Dad. We did the opening ceremony of our bakery!!!")
    .build();

new Mailer("smtp.gmail.com", 25, "your user", "your password", TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS).sendMail(email);
new Mailer("smtp.gmail.com", 587, "your user", "your password", TransportStrategy.SMTP_TLS).sendMail(email);
new Mailer("smtp.gmail.com", 465, "your user", "your password", TransportStrategy.SMTP_SSL).sendMail(email);
```

If you have two-factor login turned on, you need to generate an application specific password from your Google account.

Answer (score 0):

```
Error: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect 
to SMTP host: smtp.random.com port: 25; 
nested exception is: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

This error means that your SMTP server you provided is invalid. The code you have is correct, but smtp.random.com must not be a valid SMTP server.

I suggest you look into using Google's SMTP server that is free provided you use a valid gmail account.

Refer to this page for more information on using Gmail's STMP server: http://email.about.com/od/accessinggmail/f/Gmail_SMTP_Settings.htm

Comment: thanks ... If i use smtp.gmail.com or smtp.live.com with hotmail account, i get this :  javax.mail.MessagingException: can't determine local email address.... Any idea on this

Answer (score 0):

[This tutorial worked for me in the past](http://www.mkyong.com/java/javamail-api-sending-email-via-gmail-smtp-example/)